# OSX Jaspersoft Studio SSL Handshake

Tags: ssl-certificate, jasperserver

I was trying to connect a JasperServer 5.5 running under SSL from Jaspersoft Studio 5.5 installed in a OSX machine. I was getting the error:

*javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target*

This wiki [Using SSL certificate in Jaspersoft Studio 5.5](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-ssl-certificate-jaspersoft-studio-55) explain how to solve the problem by adding the certificate to the Jaspersoft Studio specific holder for its security certificate in the already included JRE, the exact location is in the link. However it did not work. Maybe this is a solution only for a Windows installation.

Finally after so much struggle I installed the SSL certificate in the default java folder and it worked.

```
/Library/Java/Home/lib/security
```

Even though the process works I want to be sure that is the right way to proceed so I can apply it to other machines.

**Question:**

- Is this the right way to install the certificate for Jasper Studio?
- Is Jasper Studio ignoring its included JRE installation when running in OSX?

In case somebody wants to know how I created and installed the certificate:

Using this website http://miteff.com/install-cert download the IntallCert java application and execute it against the server.

```
java InstallCert server.domain.com
```

This will connect to your SSL website and create the certificate file. Just press Enter when asked for more data.

It will create the *jssecacerts* file. Copy this file to the folder */Library/Java/Home/lib/security*

Now you will be able to access your SSL JasperServer from Jaspersoft Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposed solution is the best answer until now.

> Using this website http://miteff.com/install-cert download the IntallCert java application and execute it against the server.
>
> java InstallCert server.domain.com
>
> This will connect to your SSL website and create the certificate file. Just press Enter when asked for more data.
>
> It will create the jssecacerts file. Copy this file to the folder /Library/Java/Home/lib/security
>
> Now you will be able to access your SSL JasperServer from Jaspersoft Studio.